# Pointwise convergent subsequence of a sequence of bounded functions on a countable domain

Tags: real-analysis, sequence-of-function

I was studying analysis on Abbot's understanding analysis, and I came across this exercise:

> Let $A = \{x_1, x_2, x_3, \cdots\}$ be a countable set. For each $n \in\mathbb N$, let $f_n$ be defined on $A$ and assume there exists an $M > 0$ such that |$f_n(x)| \le  M$ for all $n \in\mathbb N$ and $x\in A$. Follow these steps to show that there exists a subsequence
> of $(f_n)$ that converges on $A$.

The textbook gave me some hints which are:

> 6
> (a) Why does the sequence of real numbers $f_n(x_1)$ necessarily contain a convergent subsequence $(f_{n_k} )$? To indicate that the subsequence of functions $(f_{n_k} ) $ is generated by considering the values of the functions at $x_1$, we will use the notation $f_{n_k} = f_{1,k}$.

> (b) Now, explain why the sequence $f_{1,k}(x_2)$ contains a convergent subsequence.

> (c) Carefully construct a nested family of subsequences $(f_{m,k})$, and show how this can be used to produce a single subsequence of $(f_n)$ that converges at every point of $A$.

I didn't have any problem with the first two (even if I still don't understand how in (b) he can tell the "form" of $(f_{n_k}(x))$, since we only know it's form if we evaluate it at $x=x_1$). On the third one though I didn't really understand how I was supposed to construct this particular sequence, so after playing around some time without getting any result I decide to take a look at the solution the author gives in the solution manual and I found this:

> Keep in mind that if $m′ > m$ then $(f_{m′,k})$ is a subsequence of $(f_{m,k})$.

I honestly don't get why this should be true, since as I understand it, it should hold only for the specific sequences of real numbers $(f_{m',k}(x_m))$ and $(f_{m,k}(x_m))$.

> $f_{n_k} = f_{k,k }= (f_{1,1}, f_{2,2}, f_{3,3},\cdots)$. The nested quality shows that $(f_{k,k})$ is a subsequence of $f_{1,k}$ and thus $f_{k,k}(x_1)$ converges. But what about $f_{k,k}(x_m)$ for an arbitrary $x_m\in A$? Well, after the first $m$ terms, we see that $f_{k,k}$ becomes a proper subsequence of $f_{m,k} (i.e., $f_{k,k}$ is eventually in $f_{m,k}$)

I also don't get why this true.

> And it follows that $f_{k,k}(x_m)$ converges. This shows $f_{k,k}$
> converges pointwisely on $A$

I would really appreciate if somebody could help me understand this proof, or even furnish me a different proof of this, since I was not able to find an alternative proof anywhere else.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: This is called "taking a diagonal subsequence".

Comment: This doesn't help me that much to understand the reasoning of why this works :(

Comment: Try to prove the case $\{ x_1,x_2\}=A$ first, see how that works. Then try to prove the case of finite $A$ by induction. I think this might be an issue of trying to do too much at once.

Comment: I think that ignoring what I didn't understand in the proof and just taking it for granted I managed to probe the case where A is finite (if I did it correctly it should be equal to the proof for the case where A has only 2 elements), but now my question is: in the proof I sketched I make use of the argument from the solution which states that after taking {f_n(x)} and evaluating it at x=x1, we obtain a convergent subsequence.

Comment: However then he says that we can extrapolate a general sequence out of it {f_nk(x)} which is a subsequence of the original for all x in A. What I don't understand are two things:

Comment: 1: Why can we do that? Isn't {f_nk(x1)} just a sequence of real numbers? How can he tell  the "general form" of the sequence {f_nk(x)}? And 2: Why this new sequence should be a subsequence of the original sequence {f_n(x)} for all x in A?

Answer (score 1):

Your comment about "not knowing the form of $(f_{n_k}(x))$" is confusing. What "form" are you referring to? It is just some subsequence of $f_n$ for which $f_{n_k}(x_1)$ converges. What more is there to know?

Let me fill various details of the construction. This is an inductive definition.

Start by setting $f_{0, n} = f_n$ for all $n$. We are going to define for each $m > 0$ a sequence of functions $(f_{m,n})_n$ and a value $y_m$ such that

- $(f_{m,n})_n$ is a subsequence of $(f_{m-1,n})_n$ (and therefore a subsequence of $(f_{M,n})_n$ for every $M < m$).
- for every $0 < i \le m, (f_{m,n}(x_i))_n \to y_i$.

When $m = 1$, we form the sequence of values $(u_n)_n = (f_{0, n}(x_1))_n$. This is a bounded sequence, so it has some convergent subsequence $(u_{n_j})_j$. Define $y_1 = \lim_j u_{n_j}$. Note that we indicate which elements of the original sequence are in the subsequence by a sequence of indices: $(n_j)_j$. We can use those indices to pick a corresponding sequence of functions:
$$f_{1, j} = f_{0, n_j}$$
so for all $j$, $$f_{1, j}(x_1) = f_{0, n_j}(x_1) = u_{n_j} \overset j \to y_1$$

Now suppose that $((f_{m,n})_n)_{m=0}^{N-1}$ and $(y_m)_{m=1}^{N-1}$ have been defined so that the two conditions above are satisfied for all $m < N$. We do the same thing as for the start: Define a new sequence $(u_n)$ by setting $u_n = f_{N-1,n}(x_N)$. Our assumptions for convergence of $f_{N-1,n}$ say nothing about $x_N$. But we do know that this sequence is bounded. Therefore once again we have some convergent subsequence $(u_{n_j})_j$. Define
$$y_N = \lim_j u_{n_j}\\(f_{N,j})_j = (f_{N-1,n_j})_j$$

Then $(f_{N,j})_j$ is by definition a subsequence of $(f_{N-1,n})_n$. So for every $i < N, (f_{N,j}(x_i))_j$ is a subsequence of $(f_{N-1,n}(x_i))_n$. But that is a convergent sequence, so the subsequence must also converge, and to the same limit. That is, for $i < N, f_{N,j}(x_i) \overset j \to y_i$. And for $i = N$, $$(f_{N,j}(x_N))_j = f_{N-1,n_j}(x_N) = u_{n_j} \overset j \to y_N$$

So in all cases, $(f_{N, j})_j$ is a subsequence of $(f_{N-1, n})_n$, and for all $i \le N, (f_{N, j}(x_i))_j \to y_i$. meeting the induction requirements.

By induction, this defines $f_{m,n}$ for all $m, n$ with the desired properties.

Comment: It took me a while to even get an idea of what you wrote, since I'm not very experienced, but please let me know if I got this right: There are infinitely many subsequences of f_n(x), and at least one of them convergences for x_1, which we denote by f_1,k. By the same reasoning we construct f_2,k and so on, so that for each m In the naturals f_m,k convergences for x_1, x_2,...x_m, and for n<m, f_m,k is a subsequence of f_n,k. Is this correct?